# Swift - Access UIVIewcontroller mutable array to UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` which contains the `UITableView`, Have created the separate class for `UITableViewCell` according to my logic I want to pass the array for every row. So I have created one mutable array and assigning the new values whenever the cell for method called.

But the mutable array I can't able to access from the `UITableViewCell` class

I have used the below code

```
class PostPage: UIViewController{
    public var imageArray = [String] ()
}

extension PostPage: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if self.UserDatas?.posts.app[indexPath.row].images?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            let cell:PostImageCell = tablView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostImageCell") as! PostImageCell
            self.imageArray = self.UserDatas?.posts.app[indexPath.row].images ?? ["String URL"]
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
    }

    class PostImageCell: UITableViewCell{
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            var mainClass : ViewController = ViewController()
            let image = self.mainClass.imageArray
        }
    }
}
```

Here am I getting the error saying like **"Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'imageArray'"**.

Comment: `var mainClass : ViewController = ViewController()`: You meant `var mainClass : PostPage = PostPage()`. But that's creating a NEW object, not the one you think of. I don't know what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** you have no VC named `ViewController`

```
var mainClass : ViewController = ViewController()
let image = self.mainClass.imageArray
```

**Second** you either make the array global

```
class Service {
   static let shared = Service()
   var imageArray = [String] ()
}
```

Then use it like this inside all the app

```
Service.shared.imagArray
```

Or create another one inside the cell custom class

```
class PostImageCell: UITableViewCell{
      var imageArray = [String] ()
}
```

and assign it in `cellForRowAt`

```
let cell = //
cell.imageArray = imageArray
```

Comment: Oh am sorry I forgot the change the UIViewController Name

Comment: @Vignesh also making it **PostPage** won't solve the problem as it'll create another instance of the vc other than the presented one

Comment: follow 1 option from what provided in answer

Comment: var mainClass : PostPage = PostPage(). self.mainClass.imageArray.count

Comment: getting empty array

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work.

Do it the other way round and pass the array in `cellForRow`

```
class PostImageCell: UITableViewCell {
    var imageArray = [String]()
}
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostImageCell") as! PostImageCell
   cell.imageArray = self.UserDatas?.posts.app[indexPath.row].images ?? []
   cell.selectionStyle = .none
   return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's right! **"Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'imageArray'"**

**PostPage** has it!!!

change this:
`var mainClass: ViewController = ViewController()`

to this:
`var mainClass: PostPage = PostPage()`

That error will gone.

But remember: it's new initialized object and contains nothing by itself.